# Proof exercise that the cardinal number of a set in $\mathbb R^2$ is $\frak c$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

let $S \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ be a countable set.

and $a \in \mathbb R^2 \setminus S$

Show that the Cardinal number of the set of lines ($y=mx+n$) in $\mathbb R^2$ that passes through point $a$ but don't cross S is $\frak c$.

What I did so far:I called the set of lines  in $\mathbb R^2$ that passes through point $a$ and crosses S, with M, and the set of lines that does not with P.
and L the set of all the lines in R that passes through a.

and so $P \cup M = L$ , and by my previous exercise I already proved that for sets such as L it's cardinal number is $\frak c$. And I know from a sentence proved in class that the cardinal number of the union of a set with a cardinal number of $\frak c$ is also $\frak c$. And from this point on I don't have an idea on how to prove that set M's cardinal number is $\frak c$. If anyone has a better idea of how to prove this, I'd be happy to hear. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is $\aleph$? Do you mean $\frak{c}$ (continuum)?

Comment: Yeah, its also called $\aleph$

Comment: Where is it denoted so? I have never seen this notation used for $\frak{c}$.

Comment: If you know the cardinality of $M$ (or a good enough upper bound), you are through because $\kappa + \lambda = \max \{\kappa, \lambda\}$ if at least one of the cardinals $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ is infinite.

Comment: $\Re$ means the real part of a complex number. Use \mathbb R to get $\mathbb R$. (Also $\frak c$ instead of $\aleph$.)

Comment: @Wojowu: It is not an uncommon notation. Especially in courses where the only two explicit cardinals of interest are $\aleph_0$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$.